# How to define a function that adds the values in HashMaps in Python?

Tags: function, dictionary, hashmap

The question is : create a `function` which will calculate the total stock worth in the cafe. You will need to remember to loop through the appropriate `maps` and lists to do this.

What I have so far :

```
menu = ("Coffee", "Tea", "Cake", "Cookies")

stock = {
    "Coffee" : 10,
    "Tea" : 17,
    "Cake" : 15,
    "Cookies" : 5,
}

price = {
    "Coffee" : 'R 12',
    "Tea" : 'R 11',
    "Cake" : 'R 20',
    "Cookies" : 'R 8',
}

def totalstock(stock):
```

Now I'm stuck, I know there should be a loop and a sum function, but I don't know how to convert the `strings` to `ints` so I can add them?

Answer (score 0):

In this case your price dictionary doesn't just have numbers so you'll have to separate the R from the number. Example:

```
coffee_price = int(price['Coffee'].split(' ')[1])
```

To explain, take the string at price['Coffee'] and split it, giving a list with 2 values. Return the second value to the int() function to be converted to an integer and stored in coffee_price.